# When you run a program that has a while loop on userInput. How to set one thing first run only

Tags: java

```
boolean program = true;
while (program == true) {
    System.out.println("Please type 1-10 for stuff")
    input = bufferedReader.readLine();
    if(firstrunonly) {
      // set bunch of stuff
    }
    if(input.equals("1") {
      // all the way to 10
    }

}
```

Okay so basically when you run the function the first time it will set stuff. Like to a database.

However when you run/compile this code the second time you don't want if(firstrunonly) to be ran again.

How do I do this?

Comment: Create a variable called `firstRun` that is initially true, and set it to false at the end of the first iteration. Or alternatively, do the setup before your `while` loop.

Comment: Wont work. By run I mean clicking run again to compile the whole code, as in it will set it to false again at the beginning

Comment: you may need to use some external resources

Comment: I read somewhere about setting arguments that could do this? Not sure

Comment: I think an external xml resource file or something may do the trick for you

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, initialize firstRun flag and change its value when you are done.

```
boolean program = true;
boolean firstrunonly = true;
while (program == true) {
    System.out.println("Please type 1-10 for stuff")
    input = bufferedReader.readLine();
    if(firstrunonly) {
      // set bunch of stuff
      firstrunonly = false;
    }
    if(input.equals("1") {
      // all the way to 10
    }

}
```

But if you only want to do it once and you do not need the first input for initialization just move it out of the while loop:

```
boolean program = true;
// set bunch of stuff
...
while (program == true) {
    System.out.println("Please type 1-10 for stuff")
    input = bufferedReader.readLine();
    if(input.equals("1") {
      // all the way to 10
    }

}
```

Comment: if he close the application and run it again program will be true again and the code will execute. He/She dont want that to happen

Comment: It was not clear at the time I wrote this. Then he should either set this flag on an external file, or if it's about DB creation, check if the DB exist and then skip the code if it does.

Comment: How do I check if DB exist? @StephaneM

Comment: Try to connect, if it succeeds the DB exists. But if it does not it might also just be down.